# How Can I Store Array Name in this case? (4 name)

Tags: java

In java, How can I save 4 doctor names and specialization in an array without a loop in my main class? Not class Doctor.
Pseudo Code:

1. MAIN MENU (4 OPTION)
2. PRESS 1 is AddDoctor
3. Enter name of doctor and specialist (No doctor have same name each other)
4. Print name and specialist of this doctor
5. Back to Main Menu
6. Redo up to 4 time. (If it enough 4 show error message)

```java
        public class Doctor 
        {
            private String name = ""; // set the name default is null
            private String specialisation = ""; // // set the specialisation default is null
        
            public void setName(String name) { // this one is save the name of the doctor
                this.name = name;
            }
            public void setSpecialisation(String specialisation) { // // this one is save the specialisation of the doctor
                this.specialisation = specialisation;
            }   
            public String getSpecialisation() // this function to get data to show what specialisation of doctor
            {
                return specialisation;
            }   
            public String getName() // // this function to get data to show what is the name of the doctor
            {
                return name;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save multiple doctors using an array:

```
// Create an empty array 
List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList();
     // Create instance of Doctor class
       Doctor d1 = new Doctor();
      // Setname here    
       d1.setName("Name1");
      // set Specialisation here
       d1.setSpecialisation("Specialisation1");
      // Add this object to array
       doctors.add(d1);
       Doctor d2 = new Doctor();
       d2.setName("Name2");
       d2.setSpecialisation("Specialisation2");
       doctors.add(d2);
       //...similarly for other doctros
    System.out.println(doctors.size());
```

If you want to use it from menu create a function like:

```
class AddDoctor {
List<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList();

    private void addDoctor(String name, String specialisation) {
          // Check already exists
           if(checkAlreadyExists(name)) {
            System.out.println("Already exists witht this name")
           }
          // Create instance of Doctor class
           Doctor d = new Doctor();
          // Setname here    
           d.setName(name);
          // set Specialisation here
           d.setSpecialisation(specialisation);
          // Add this object to array
           doctors.add(d);
    }
}

private boolen checkAlreadyExists(String name) {
   for(Doctor d : doctors) {
    if(d.getName().equals(name)) {
      return true;
     }
    }
return false;
}
```

Take the user inputs(name and specialisation) and call this method from the menu like:

```
addDoctor("Name1", "specialisation1");
```

Comment: How Can I limit just only 4 doctor. 
For example: if name[0] [2] [3] exists. And want to add doctor into [1]. How can I do this?